# Translate SelectMany in Select to PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two entities

```cs
class Qwe
{
     Guid Id;
     List<Guid> ZxcItems; //links to Zxc
     string SomeProperty;
}

class Zxc
{
     Guid Id;
     Guid QweId; //Link to Qwe
     string SomeProperty2;
}
```

Now i need to prepare `IQueryable` for future translation to SQL request (`npgsql`)
My code is like this:

```cs
_dbContext.Qwes.Include(x=>x.SomethingINeed)
     .Select(x=> new SomeClass { 
          Value = string.Join(" ", 
               x.SomeProperty, 
               string.Join(" ", x.ZxcItems.Select(y=>y.SomeProperty2)) 
     });
```

when i'm trying to `InsertFromQueryAsync`, i get the
`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Length cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'length')'`

as option, i've tried this:

```cs
_dbContext.Qwes.Include(x=>x.SomethingINeed)
          .Select(x=> new SomeClass { 
               Value = string.Join(" ", 
                    x.SomeProperty, 
                    x.ZxcItems.SelectMany(y=>y.SomeProperty2)
          });
```

but then i get `The LINQ expression 'y => y.SomeProperty2' could not be translated.`

Comment: You need two joins : Value = string.Join(" ", 
                   x.SomeProperty, 
                   string.Join("",x.ZxcItems.Select(y=>y.SomeProperty2)))  SelectMany is not needed.
         });

Comment: but this is literally my first option

Comment: `SelectMany` from `string` prorperty? It is not translatable. You can do `SelectMany` only from collection property which represents set of entities.

Comment: Try this :            List<SomeClass> results = _dbContext.Qwes.Select(x => new SomeClass()
            {
                Value = x.SomeProperty + " " +  string.Join(" ", x.ZxcItems.Select(y => y.SomeProperty2))
                
            }).ToList();

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv `ZxcItems` is list of entities. As you see, i need to get a string in `Value` property.

Comment: @jdweng i can't do `ToList()` here, i need to get `IQueryable`

Comment: The use VAR (instead of List<SomeClass>) and remove ToList()